# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando un numero contenga 0 no se muestre el resultado de su división? Java

Tags: java

Soy bastante nuevo en esto y me cuesta entender el funcionamiento de algunas cosas, agradecería me pudieran ayudar a ver mis errores.

Lo que quiero hacer es que a partir de dos arreglos, se divida cada numero de estos por su equivalente en posición dentro del otro arreglo, mostrando el resultado de esa división solo si los elementos en ella (dividendo y divisor) no contienen 0 (ejemplos 150, 107, 10).

También quiero hacer que solo se vea un decimal en el resultado, creo que esto funciona a medias ya que me muestra un decimal, pero solo son 0s.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
double div;
    System.out.println("Divisiones: ");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    div = B[i]/A[i];
    String numCadenaA = String.valueOf(A[i]);
    String numCadenaB = String.valueOf(B[i]);
    String buscar = "0";
    int buscadoA;
    int buscadoB;
        buscadoA = numCadenaA.indexOf("0");
        buscadoB = numCadenaA.indexOf("0");            
    if(buscadoA == -1 && buscadoB == -1){

        System.out.println("La division es de " + String.format("%.1f", div) + " y los valores divididos se encuentran en la posicion " + i);
        
    }
}
```

A [96, 77, 66, 57, 52, 47, 44, 23, 16, 2]

B [120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 117, 115, 111, 107]

El resultado de esto es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes corregir el codigo, reemplazando:

```java
     buscadoB = numCadenaA.indexOf("0");
```

por

```java
     buscadoB = numCadenaB.indexOf("0");
```

Dado que esta volviendo a buscar en la cadena para el array `A`.

Una versión mas corta seria:

```java
double div;
    System.out.println("Divisiones: ");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String buscar = "0";
    String candena = B[i]+' dividió en '+A[i]
    if( candena.indexOf(buscar) == -1){
       div = (double) B[i]/A[i];
       DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
       String result= df.format(div);
       System.out.println("La division es de " + result + " y los valores "+ candena +"se encuentran en la posicion " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿tiene alguna idea de que error tengo en lo de los números decimales? Es que por ejemplo si la division fuera 111/9 = 12.3333... Lo que muestra es 12.0. También agradezco su anterior respuesta, me sirvió mucho.

Comment: Si claro el `String.format` redondea y ejecuta una acción no deseada, debe usar la clase `DecimalFormat`   he actualizado el codigo.

Comment: Perdón creo que no se entendió lo que quiero hacer, lo que busco es que se muestre solo 1 decimal, por ejemplo si el resultado es 12,333.... que se muestre solo 12,3. Lo que me esta mostrando ahora (usando su código) es solo 12, antes con el código que yo compartí  me mostraba 12,0

Comment: El problema consiste en que esta operando con números enteros, por lo tanto no se convierte realmente a un `double`, debe declara explicitamente que la operación sea `double` y que luego se guarde en una variable de tipo `double`
de esta forma 
`double resultado =  (double) 1/3;`